# Scala: type mismatch found in mapping

Tags: list, scala

Error: type mismatch; found : List[List[(Char, Int)]] required: List[(Char, Int)] at q<- x

```
a2 reduceLeft ((x,y)=>  
  for{  
    q<- x  
    b<- y  
  } yield (q::b::Nil)  
)
```

where, a2  : List[List[(Char, Int)]].

If a2 is `List[List[(Char, Int)]]`, x is `List[(Char, Int)]`, so q is `(Char, Int)`, and so is b, how it found `List[List[(Char, Int)]]`?

Comment: Can you post a good example of what you are trying to achieve so we can suggest a good solution?

Comment: It's my assignment, so can't tell what I am trying to achieve. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `yield` returns a `List[(Char, Int)]` so the for loop returns a `List[List[(Char, Int)]]`.

Therefore, the `reduceLeft` complains since it expects the return type to be `List[(Char, Int)]`.